# insert a page into document while sending envelope using DOCUSIGN

Tags: document, signature, docusignapi

I am new to docusign and the APIs.

However I am trying to understand what would be the best way to achieve my usecase.

I have a document which can have (1+) middle pages apart from the first and last page where user has to sign the document.

To optimize this is a solution i am thinking but not nearing the answer.

1. Create a template with three pages.
2. While sending envelope to user depending upon the scenario (the middle pages can be 1+...) I am trying to create the pages dynamically and trying to insert between the exising document of template.

Is this possible?

Or should i need to try Composite Template API for this by making the inital Template as Two seperate template and insert the dynamic one as "inline" template?

Comment: You might be able to use templates in your workflow, but I want to understand your use case a little more.  Is there a finite set of documents you will be sending (for instance you have a 3-page, 5-page, and 7-page envelope where the first and last pages are the same), or is always a variable amount of pages in the middle?   If it's always a variable, un-predictable amount then you might just want to send a signature request on document each time instead of through a template, however you still might be able to use Templates possibly.  Let me know more about your use case...

Answer (score 0):

One Envelope with three documents presented to Signer: use Composite Template form of envelope per your final suggestion of the following structure (REST OR SOAP):

```
Composite Templates
    Composite Template
      Server Template (Static Document PDF and Recipient Role and Tabs)
      Inline Template
           Recipient Role 
    Composite Template
      Server Template (structure PDF and Tabs)
      Document (actual PDF bytes for dynamic document)
    Composite Template
      Server Template (Static Document PDF and Recipient Role and Tabs)
```

This is NOT the solution if your want one document (not one PDF) in the Envelope presented to the Signer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have a quick question about the note. Do you mean this will not work if i just want the final user to see only One PDF document? Because though i have many documents i would expect it to work with just only one PDF document when they sign. To make it clean for them.. Any thoughts?

Comment: talk to your account manager about our document visibility feature. Also, think of an envelope as sealed when sent, so "adding" documents with tabs generally isn't going to work unless you are adding a signer after current signer but before it is complete. One of our harder tasks to accomplish, better to have all, and correct signers. Also my one document comments was about presenting all pages continuous as one named document in the envelope vs 3 docs in envelope

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Have a general question. Is there a way to insert a Table field in docusign?

Comment: Linux Developer - Would you create a couple new questions, I think it is like the following: 

-How can you place data in a secure field in a DocuSign Envelope
-How can you get data from a secure field in a DocuSign Envelope