# How to insert dynamic rows into Docusign document while creating envelope

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

This is continuation to the following post
[insert a page into document while sending envelope using DOCUSIGN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979644/insert-a-page-into-document-while-sending-envelope-using-docusign)

I have rephrased my question due to poor explanation before.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am not successful in finding a documentation about the following scenario.

I am trying to find whether is it possible to "dynamically" insert table in a PDF while creating an envelope out of Template. Assume that you have created a template with one signature and you want to give an option to insert other rows for multiple sinature.

No information found so far. Thats why i am trying to see if there is a way which i am not aware of.

Any reference to online material is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I'd suggest you check out the DocuSign Developer Center (http://www.docusign.com/developer-center), as it contains a wealth of information to get you up and running quickly with the DocuSign APIs.

Comment: Yes i did. But I could not find if its possible to "dynamically" insert table in a PDF while creating an envelope out of Template. Assume that you have created a template with one signature and you want to give an option to insert other rows for multiple sinature. No information found so far. Thats why i am trying to see if there is a way which i am not aware of

Comment: Your question doesn't describe any of what you've just said in your comment. If you want decent feedback, I'd suggest you update your question to clearly/fully describe what you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Linux Developer - Are you trying to emulate adobe LiveCycle dynamic document or are you trying to support line elements like for Purchase Order? Is this data read only or editable by the signer?

Comment: Actually i have both. In one situation i have only for VIEW similar to purchase order. In other use-case i wanted to allow dynamic way to include more signers.

Answer (score 2):

One option to facilitate your use case might be to create multiple Templates in DocuSign -- one for each possible number of signers, and then have your application logic determine which Template to use during Envelope creation based upon some logic within your application.  For example, let's assume the following scenario:

- Your application is an online loan processing application that collects information from the borrower, and then uses DocuSign to present the loan documents for signature.
- If there IS NOT a co-borrower, then you only need signature from one person (the borrower).
- If there IS a co-borrower, then you need signatures from two people (the borrower AND the co-borrower).

In DocuSign, you create two (nearly identical) templates:

- **Loan Docs - 1 signer** :  This template defines a single recipient role (Borrower) and the document(s) in the template only contain space for the Borrower's signature.
- **Loan Docs - 2 signers** : This template defines two recipient roles (Borrower and Co-borrower) and the document(s) in the template contain spaces for both the Borrower's signature and the Co-borrower's signature.

If your application determines there is no co-borrower, then it creates the Envelope using the first template (**Loan Docs - 1 signer**). If your application determines there IS a co-borrower, then it creates the Envelope using the second template (**Loan Docs - 2 signers**).

So, that's one way of handling it.  Another way of handling things would be the following:

- Create a single template that defines Recipient Roles (and corresponding tags in the document(s)) for the maximum number of Signers you'd ever have.
- When you make the "Create Envelope" API call using that template, only supply recipient information for the number of signers that are required for that specific Envelope.

For example, let's say that your template defines 2 recipient roles (Borrower and Co-borrower), and contains signature tags for each recipient.

- If your application determines that there are 2 signers, you supply information for both signers in the "Create Envelope" API call.
- If your application determines that there is just 1 signer, you supply information for only the Borrower in the "Create Envelope" API call.

DocuSign will simply drop/ignore any tags belonging to recipient roles that you did not supply information for in the "Create Envelope" API call.  So, in the latter case (info supplied for only one signer), the space(s) in the document(s) where the second signer's signature would have appeared still exists -- it'll just be empty/blank (because there is no second signer for the Envelope).

Comment: do we any update on it? the above will work if we know the maximum number of signaturee what if the number of signaturee could be different and we don't know the max number of signature either.